# How can infrasounds pass through walls and other solid objects without dissipation?

Tags: acoustics

I have to do a physics project about infrasounds and i tried to search for some basic things about that but i couldnot find anything, can someone explain me why infrasounds can pass through walls without dissipation,thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrasound

Answer (score 1):

A seismic wave can have a wavelength larger than a building.   Thus, the
wave may MOVE the building, but not cause structural strains, because
the building is like a tiny cork, bobbing up and down on long, gentle waves.
Infrasound, if its wavelength is larger than an obstacle, goes around the
obstacle without deflecting or losing energy.

It is possible for a large wall to deflect a fraction of a millimeter without
much energy absorbed.   For the same wall to ripple one millimeter at high frequency, over several-wavelengths distances, would dissipate much
more energy.   More closely spaced bending, done more often, means more
work.

Similarly, human eyes don't focus ultraviolet light, because the fibrous inner
structure of the lens is cloudy to the short wavelength.   Longer (visible) wavelengths shine right through (the fibers are smaller than visible lightwaves).
Size of the fibers makes them incapable of blocking of the longer wavelengths.